# Query returning argument null exception

Tags: c#, linq

I have the method below which I am using to fetch data

```
    public async Task<Mydata> GetMyData(int myId)
    {
        return await DbContext.Data
            .Where(x => x.ParentId == myId || x.ParentId == null) && 
            x.status != FileStatus.Testing && x.status != FileStatus.Commanding);
    }
```

All I get is the error below. Is this wrong?

ArgumentNullException

> `'IQueryable<File>'` does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and
>   no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter'  accepting a first
>   argument of type `'IQueryable<Mydata>'` could be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an  assembly reference?)

How can i correct this?

Answer (score 2):

There's no need for async/await here, because nothing asynchronous is happening.  The code in the method appears trying to return an `IQueryable` of something called `Mydata` (whatever the model type in `DbContext.Data` is).  So just return that:

```
public IQueryable<Mydata> GetMyData(int myId)
{
    return DbContext.Data
        .Where(x => (x.ParentId == myId || x.ParentId == null) && 
        x.status != FileStatus.Testing && x.status != FileStatus.Commanding);
}
```

**Edit:** You also had mis-matched parentheses, the code posted was invalid.  I've matched the parentheses, though can't guarantee if the resulting logic is what you intend.  Debugging will help you narrow that down though.

Comment: I don't see any difference in the code i pasted and what you corrected apart from the await. This does not work.

Comment: @user2320476: Define "does not work".  The difference *is* removing the async/await.

Comment: All i get is the name x does not exist in the current context

Comment: @user2320476: Which is a different error.  Looking at the code, you appear to also have a syntax error from mismatched parentheses.  I'll update the answer now.

Comment: This is a similar query that works in sql.  select * from dbo.data where
  (parentid = '2215'
  or parentid is null)
  and statusId != 7
  and statusId != 8

Comment: @user2320476: In that SQL query you are explicitly grouping the `OR` clause, so it has higher precedent than the `AND` clauses.  You may have intended to do that in the C# code, but forgot to match the parentheses.  If that is your intent, go ahead and enclose that clause in parentheses.

Comment: I am not sure what to close. can you send me a code sample please?

Comment: @user2320476: You would enclose *exactly the same logic* that's in the SQL query.  I've updated the answer to demonstrate.

Comment: I am back to the initial error Argument exception. This does not work

Comment: @user2320476: Can you update the question to include the code you've changed, how you're calling the method, and the exact error you're getting?

Comment: I used the exact code you modified so no need to paste it again. It has red squiggly lines with the same error i first reported.

Comment: @user2320476: It may seem redundant, but it's important to get a complete look at what's happening.  The fact that the initial change modified the first error means that *something* was fixed.  The overall error may be slightly different in a subtle way that you aren't familiar with (which is why you're here).  Please provide information about the error in the question.

Comment: I would recommend reading David's response again. You are creating a Task method with await on dbcontext.Data... there is nothing Async about your dbcontext.Data that you need to use `await` for (which is what your error is). Change your method to what's defined in his response and also where you are calling this method from.